# onSubmit not working for text input with multiline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a texfield which clears the input text typed when enter key is pressed it triggers the onSubmit function, but for some reason when Multline is set to true, the onSubmit doesn't work.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const addMessage = e => {
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={addMessage}>
      <TextField
        // multiline="true"
        inputRef={inputRef}
        multiline="true"
        id="filled-basic"
        label="Filled"
        variant="filled"
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

I added a codesandbox as well which has the code to make it easier https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-morning-w2gqx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per material ui's [multiline](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#multiline) doc:

> The multiline prop transforms the text field into a textarea or a TextareaAutosize

1. Provide a boolean value to `multiple` prop
2. In order to submit form upon `enter` key press, provide an `onKeydown` like below.
3. To auto resize after form submit, you can use `ref` and set the `height` to `auto`.

```js
export default function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  const addMessage = e => {
    console.log("hi");
    inputRef.current.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "";
  };

  const handleKeyDown = event => {
    if (event.which === 13) {//<------use enter key to submit form
      inputRef.current.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].style.height = "auto"; //<------resize text area
      addMessage(event);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addMessage}>
      <TextField
        ref={inputRef}
        multiline //<-----see here
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} //<-----see here
        id="filled-basic"
        label="Filled"
        variant="filled"
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-enter-key-issue-fix-0p2sw?file=/src/App.js)

**Note**: You can also consider to submit form upon `shift + enter` key (not just enter). This way, user can hit enter to type text in the next line of the text area.(better user experience)

```js
//use shift + enter key to submit form
if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.shiftKey) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for the explanation, was just curious when enter is pressed, the textfield doesn't resize instantly, it remains large, is there a way to fix that @gdh

Comment: updated the answer...use the same codesandbox link (just refresh page)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, much appreciated, can you explain to me how you got it to resize

Comment: no problem .... we can resize using `ref` and adjusting `height` to auto ... point num 3 in answer .. also left some comments in code..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

Material UI component TextField takes a boolean value for multiline. Either set multiline={true} or just include multiline as in:

```
<TextField
  inputRef={inputRef}
  multiline
  id="filled-basic"
  label="Filled"
  variant="filled"
/>
```

For more information see: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#multiline

Comment: Multline is working, the problem is that when enter key is pressed, it doesn't call the onSubmit, instead it goes to a new line